# I realize I am Over Qualified for the Company

Tags: work-environment, new-job, job-change

They made me sweat during job interviews, I became a hungry go getter, I really want the job, the company is impressive with its venue and furnitures and reputation.

But once I became part of their IT department, I realize that they are messy, they have no procedures, and most people just do their tasks for passive reasons (to avoid taking the blame).

I wouldn't be so critical if the company I joined for a month now wasn't big and old enough to have already established organizational plans. Especially when each department depends on others.

I am not under pressure at the moment, but I am renowned for being good at foreshadowing.

The other thing is that I discovered how they worked their previous projects, a complete disaster, which make me wonder: where were all of these managers with impressive job titles?

Indeed, the first couple of weeks, I tolerated the verbal task assignment, brain-storming, and different action taking, I thought it was an exception, and I was wrong! It feels alarming.

Recently, I was assigned a task that I didn't know anything about. 48 hours later, I come with a solution, formally described.

I discuss it with my boss, the assigner, he approves it, and tells me to "market" it to my teammates. This had a strange frustrating impact on me.

Should I take classes in management to become project manager?

Is this casual? Am I too sensitive?

Comment: It is not unethical to decide that a company is not a good fit shortly after accepting a position, especially if they advertised themselves as more attractive than they really were. They only have themselves to blame.

Comment: Being brutally selfish, a job should be enjoyable, pay good money, and leave you with an improved CV. How does that job rate in these respects?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a difference between expectation and reality. Perhaps because of the interview process.

What was your main motivation for applying for that role? What did you see it giving you and where are you hoping to go?

Explore your options. Is there scope for this company offering you what you want? Is it worth waiting the time it takes to get you there?

Is there a chance for you to champion the change the company needs in organisational process (that you thought it had)? Is there scope for you changing the interview process so they don't hire anyone with the same expectation/reality gap again? Do you want to do those things?

Give yourself a time limit. If by the time the time limit is up, and it's definitely clear that company can't get you where you want to be, then move on. Life is too short to waste your time working for a corporation that isn't giving you what you want.